# Usage of nested overridden methods in super class methods in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, subclass, super

If I have a abstract class called `SuperClass` and a sub class to it, called `SubClass`, with methods declared like this:

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
    public void foo() {
    //Do something
    bar();
    }
    
    public void bar() {
    //Does something in one way
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    @Override
    public void bar() {
    //Does something in other way
    }
}
```

And when I call the inherited method `foo()` on `SubClass` instance:

```
SubClass sub = new SubClass();
sub.foo();
```

Will `bar()` method executed inside of `foo()` method be the one defined in `SubClass` or in the `SuperClass`?

Comment: Why not simply try it yourself? Print something to the console to see which method is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will call method from SubClass